# Averaging attributes from small line segments into a new line segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, arcgis-10.5

I'm working on a project which involves combining shorter road line segments into longer ones where needed using ArcGIS 10.5. Each segment has an attribute of average traffic flow. For example, there may be four segments less than 100 feet long that have different values for traffic flow, I want to combine these into one segment that has the average traffic flow of the four segments. I'm looking for a way to automate this process so that manual calculations wouldn't need to be done.

Comment: How are you deciding to group those four (for example) segments into one? Do they have an attribute value in common?

Comment: Also please indicate your license level of ArcGIS 10.5. If you have an advanced license and an attribute in common, [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/dissolve.htm) will do the trick.

Comment: These segments are neighboring.

Comment: I have an advanced license, but I don't have ArcInfo workstation installed.

Comment: An advanced license is all you need for Dissolve. It's not clear, though, how you will make decisions about grouping your segments. I suggest you [edit] your post to include a sample of your data (both map and table forms would be helpful) illustrating which segments would/would not be in a group. Or are you planning to do the groupings manually?